# Mostrar una ventana de información (infowindow) al hacer click en un POI de Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con la API de Google Maps y me gustaría ver el `POI`  una ventana de información cuando se hace clic en ellos.

Sé que puedo hacer un `setOnPoiClickListener` y  llamar a un  `onPoiClick`, pero de aquí en adelante no logro mostrar la ventana de información.

¿Alguna idea que me puedan compartir?

```
@Override

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        final LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin11)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                mMap.addMarker( new MarkerOptions()
                        .icon( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource( R.drawable.pin ) )
                        .anchor( 0.0f, 1.0f )
                        .position( latLng ) );

            }
        });


        **mMap.setOnPoiClickListener( new GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPoiClick(PointOfInterest poi) {**

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Primeramente, ¿estas mostrando el mapa? ¿obtuviste una API KEY?

Comment: si el mapa si se muestra y si tengo la API KEY, de echo ya pude lograr añadir un marcador y muestra un MarkerOptions con el titulo pero al hacer click. pero no lo logro con los POI.

Comment: Usa setOnMarkerClickListener en lugar de setOnMapLongClickListener u setOnPoiClickListener

Answer (score -1):

Para hacer un marcador "clickable" puedes implementar el listener [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener), ejemplo:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Map dataModel = (Map)markers.get(marker);
            String title = (String)dataModel.get("title");

           Log.i("Map", "Click en marker : " + title);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Si usas `setOnPoiClickListener` se supone que el marcador es un "punto de interes" lo cual generalmente no es.

Comment: Entiendo, pero en este caso la ventana de información se mostraría en el Marker que agregue y no en los POI  "Puntos de Interés" que se muestran por defecto en el Mapa. Te comento un poco mas.Lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer clic  los puntos de Interés me muestre la información de ese punto  nombre teléfono horarios y a esta ventana añadir un link a un blog de este mismo sitio, mas o menos haci https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-poi

Comment: Si usas un Marker solo define un OnMarkerClickListener y aquí puedes mostrar un infoWindow

Comment: correcto pero no uso un  Marker en el mapa  quisiere usar los mismos POI de el mapa para mostrar la información. Similar al PlacePicker https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker?hl=es-419

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker?hl=es-419                                                                                                                       este es el código del PlacePicker para capturar la informacion del lugar no se si se pueda añadir a un POI